# Running a long script in PHP

Tags: php, import, scripts

I'm trying to upload over 2,000 products with images from XML to my site. I wrote a script that does this. But this script takes a very long time and I can't get the upload status of each product. I don't want advice like "make the execution time of the PHP script longer". I want to understand how to run very big scripts with PHP, divide tasks, and monitor each product's loading status.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some settings to your script to reduce count of imported products in one run. The simplest way - add fields like "Import from" and "Imported count". You can run your script several times playing with "Import from" parameter and import 200 products (for example) per one time.